# I try to make reroll command but I got an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "!reroll") {
        let winner = client.channels.cache
            .get("1046154195406946394")
            .messages.fetch("1051062563045117952")
            .reactions.cache.get("")
            .users.cache.filter((users) => !users.bot)
            .random(winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1));

        message.channel.send(`${winner}`);
    }
});
```

I tried to make this command for my giveaway not but I got an error. Can someone tell me how I can cache reactions for a specific `message.id`?

Comment: please add printed error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

[`messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise so you need to resolve it first. You can use async-await for this. Something like this should work:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!reroll') {
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get('1046154195406946394');
    let msg = await channel.messages.fetch('1051062563045117952');
    let usersReacted = msg
      .reactions.cache.get('')
      .users.cache.filter((users) => !users.bot);
    let winner = usersReacted.random(winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1));

    message.channel.send(`${winner}`);
  }
});
```